# Python pandas, extracting data from file

Tags: python, pandas, text-files

I have already read all Pandas documentation, but I think I need a practical example to understand.

I have this .TXT file with all my sql data.

> INSERT INTO `jos_users` VALUES ('4065', 'lel lel', 'joel',
>   'chazaa@frame.com', 'd0c9f71c7bc8c9', 'Membre', '0', '0', '2',
>   '2013-01-31 17:15:29', '2014-12-10 11:29:13', '', '{}');
>
> INSERT INTO `jos_users` VALUES ('4066', 'jame lea', 'jamal',
>   'jamal.stan@frame.com', 'd0c9f71c7774c9', 'Membre', '0', '0', '2',
>   '2012-11-31 08:15:29', '2012-12-10 12:29:13', '', '{}');

(Around 17.000 lines) and I don't have any columns name in my .txt file.

**What I want to achieve :**

1. Create columns myself
2. Re-arrange content based on the columns (for example, I want to select the columns 1 and display it)

My code right now, which display junk :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.set_option('display.mpl_style', 'default') 
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (15, 5)


df = pd.read_csv('2.txt', sep=',', na_values=['g'], error_bad_lines=False)

print df
```

Comment: As a first step you need to clean your TXT file, at the moment it's a SQL script not a csv file, you could strip out everything up to and including the left bracket and then remove the trailing bracket and any new lines.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but how can I do that ?

Comment: `What I want to achieve : Create columns myself`  Containing what data, exactly?

Comment: `Re-arrange content based on the columns (for example, I want to select the columns 1 and display it)`  How would displaying column 1 be rearranging your data?

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is an example script I just knocked up, I don't profess that this is the most efficient method of cleaning your SQL script, ideally if you have access to the original DB then you should be able to export it as a csv.

Anyway what the following does is to open you text file and remove the `insert into`, open and close braces, and quoting characters (not necessary but I prefer this style) and any extraneous spaces.

```
In [91]:

with open(r'c:\data\clean.csv', 'wt') as clean:
    with open(r'c:\data\temp sql.txt', 'rt') as f:
        for line in f:
            if len(line) > 0:
                l = line.replace('INSERT INTO jos_users VALUES (', '')
                l = l.replace(", '", ",'")
                l = l.replace("'",'')
                l = l.replace(');','')
                clean.write(l)
clean.close()
f.close()
# read the file back in, there is no header so you need to specify this 
df = pd.read_csv(r'c:\data\clean.csv', header=None)
df
Out[91]:
     0         1      2                     3               4       5   6   \
0  4065   lel lel   joel      chazaa@frame.com  d0c9f71c7bc8c9  Membre   0   
1  4066  jame lea  jamal  jamal.stan@frame.com  d0c9f71c7774c9  Membre   0   

   7   8                    9                    10  11  12  
0   0   2  2013-01-31 17:15:29  2014-12-10 11:29:13 NaN  {}  
1   0   2  2012-11-31 08:15:29  2012-12-10 12:29:13 NaN  {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  The following method is much slower than writing the altered data to a file, then  using read_csv() to read the altered data into a DataFrame.  For a 34,000 line file it took ~23 minutes v. ~3 seconds.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
#Pre-allocate all the space needed by your DataFrame:
df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(18000), columns=np.arange(13))

pattern = r""" #Find all single quoted sequences:
    '          #Match a single quote, followed by...
    (          #(start a capture group)
      [^']*    #not a single quote, 0 or more times, followed by...
    )          #(end the capture group)
    '          #a single quote
"""

regex = re.compile(pattern, flags=re.X)

f = open('data.txt')

for i, line in enumerate(f):
    data = re.findall(regex, line)  #findall() returns a list of all the strings that matched the pattern's capture group 

    if data:
        df.iloc[i] = data  #insert data at row i

print df

--output:--
         0         1      2                     3               4       5    6    7    8                    9                    10   11   12
0      4065   lel lel   joel      chazaa@frame.com  d0c9f71c7bc8c9  Membre    0    0    2  2013-01-31 17:15:29  2014-12-10 11:29:13        {}
1      4066  jame lea  jamal  jamal.stan@frame.com  d0c9f71c7774c9  Membre    0    0    2  2012-11-31 08:15:29  2012-12-10 12:29:13        {}
...
...
1798    NaN       NaN    NaN                   NaN             NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                  NaN                  NaN  NaN  NaN
1799    NaN       NaN    NaN                   NaN             NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                  NaN                  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

**re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)**
Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall

Writing the altered data to a file, then reading it in using read_csv():

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import time

pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

pattern = r"""
    '          #Match a single quote, followed by...
    (          #start a capture group.
      [^']*    #not a quote, 0 or more times, followed by...
    )          #end capture group.
    '          #a single quote
"""

regex = re.compile(pattern, flags=re.X)

fin = open('data2.txt')  #The two insert statemetns in the op, repeated 17,000 times
fout = open('data.csv', 'w')

results = {}

for line in fin: 
    data = re.findall(regex, line)  

    if data:
        print(*data, file=fout, sep=',')  

fin.close()
fout.close()

df = pd.read_csv(
    'data.csv', 
    sep=',', 
    header=None,
    names=np.arange(13),  #column names: 0 - 12
)


print(df)
```